# Fourier transform of a product of sinusoidal functions

Tags: fourier-analysis

Given the function:
$$x(t)=A_1\cos(\omega_1 t+\phi)$$
its Fourier transform is:
$$X(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}A_1 e^{-i\phi}\delta(\omega_1-\omega)+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}A_1 e^{i\phi}\delta(\omega_1+\omega)$$
More in general, given the function:
$$x(t)=\prod_{k=1}^NA_k \cos(\omega_kt+\phi_k)$$
what is the formula of Fourier transform $X(\omega)$ of $x(t)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any product of cosines can be written as a sum of cosines using $2 \cos a \cos b = \cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b)$.

Comment: Maybe it helps to write it as $\prod A_k (e^{-i\omega_k t+\varphi_k}+e^{i\omega_k t+\varphi_k})/2$, then factor out the product and sum in the exponent. FT is then done on a sum of $\exp$'s, which should be easy for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you extend Willie Wong's comment on the [Product-to-sum identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) (works better than mine)
$$
\cos \theta_1 \cos \theta_2= {\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2) \over 2}
$$
(with $\omega_kt+\varphi_k\color{black}{=\theta_k)}$ to $3$ cosines
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\cos \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 \cos \theta_3&=& {\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2) \over 2}\cos \theta_3\\
&=&\scriptstyle{\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2+\theta_3) +\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2-\theta_3) + \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2+\theta_3)+\cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2-\theta_3) \over 4},
\end{eqnarray}
$$
you recognize that all $2^{3-1}$ $"\pm"$ combinations of $\theta_k$ appear. So we get
$$
x(t)=\prod_{k=1}^NA_k \cos(\omega_kt+\phi_k)=
\frac A{2^{N-1}}\sum_{b=0}^{2^{N-1}-1}\cos\left(\sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^{b_k}\theta_k\right),
$$
with $\left(\prod_{k=1}^NA_k\right)$ and $b=\sum_{k=1}^{N} 2^{k-1}b_k$. Then use what you already know about the Fourier Transform and you're done.

Comment: Could you fix the answer above? I couldn't find  what are $A$ and $b$ or $b_k$ in your equation above.